In Visio, is it possible to have the text of the decision of the UML activity inside the shape?
I'm creating a flow chart, for which I'm using UML Activity shapes.
While using the Decision shape, I notice that the text is put below the shape, which makes it difficult to read, once combined with a connector (which is general behaviour):

Is there a way to get the text inside the Decision shape, as done in the Action shape?
Thanks in advance

Select the shape, then use the text block tool on the ribbon, you can move the text with the mouse. Click the Pointer tool when done. This is standard for almost any Visio shape.
